# Skip one of promise on if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, es6-promise, ramda.js

I have a situation where I want to work with handling multiple promises.

Suppose I have 3 variable

```
fileOption, setupOptions, moveOption
```

base on each variable I am requesting functions like

```
file.validate(token)
    .then((token) => file.create(fileOption))
    .then((file) => setup ? file.getToken(userfromSetup) : Promise.resolve({}))
    .then((token) => setup ? file.setup(setupOptions) : Promise.resolve({}))
    .then((data) => moveOption ? file.getTokenForMove(userFromMove) : Promise.resolve({}))
    .then((token) => moveOption ? file.move(moveOption) : Promise.resolve({}))
    .then((success)=>logger.log(`file created successfully`))
    .catch((err)=>logger.error(`Error`))
```

If **setupOption** is undefined then I don't want to get token for it and create a setup for file and same for **moveOption**. For creating a setup I need to create token first and same for move

So my concern is how to **skip** the promises and unnecessary empty promise return if above variables are **undefined**

Comment: I would check for null before you start making any promises. Then you can tailor your code however you like.

Comment: It's called a "promise chain" for a reason. If `setupOption` if defined outside of the chain, as it seems to be the case here, then why even start making promises without checking it first?

Comment: All variables are dynamic contents. they will at runtime. That's why I have checked inside the promise.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var file_promise = file.validate(token)
.then((token) => file.create(fileOption))
.then((file) => setup ? file.getToken(userfromSetup) : Promise.resolve({}))
.then((token) => setup ? file.setup(setupOptions) : Promise.resolve({}));
if(moveOption){
    file_promise = file_promise.then((data)=>{file.getTokenForMove(userFromMove)});
}
file_promise.then((token) => moveOption ? file.move(moveOption) : Promise.resolve({}))
.then((success)=>logger.log(`file created successfully`))
.catch((err)=>logger.error(`Error`));
```

You can simply use a variable, and regular conditional statements to chain, or not, the promises.

The problem that might arise from this is that each step cannot be certain of what it will receive, but you code creates parameters for the functions called in then() but they do not use them, so it shouldn't cause any trouble. Else, you'd do exactly like you are doing, and resolve with a default value or something.